# Terminate process SILENTLY using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, silent

I am simply trying to kill a process using a batch that calls a vbscript, but i need the vbscript to do it silently. Or can this not be done without UAC prompting for privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used WMIC instead

`wmic process where name="wscript.exe" call terminate > nul`

Answer (score 0):

You can **TASKKILL** a process with PID on a remote system, using different user credentials, and **TASKLIST** to list them.

At a command prompt type `taskkill /?` or this [taskkill on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb491009.aspx). Using PID will prevent terminating a wrong process with the same. For example, a computer with both 2007 and 2010 versions of office installed and only the 2007 version needs terminating.

See `tasklist /?` or this [tasklist on technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx).

You can even combine **PSEXEC** to fill the gap which TASKLIST cannot do remotely.

Comment: I've done this, but it does not kill the task silently as I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

To run a script or application in the Windows Shell using the ShellExecute method (cf msdn.microsoft.com):

```
Syntax
      .ShellExecute "application", "parameters", "dir", "verb", windowFlag
Key
   application   The file to execute (required)
   parameters    Arguments for the executable
   dir           Working directory
   verb          The operation to execute (runas/open/edit/print)
   windowFlag    View mode application window (normal=1, hide=0, ...)
```

You can try this:

```
Set denyUAC = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
denyUAC.ShellExecute "cscript", "D:\demo\vbscript.vbs", "", "runas", 0
```